# MongoDB service not running in Fedora

Tags: linux, mongodb, fedora

Just installed a clean version of mongodb on Fedora 17 64-bit, but the Mongo service wont run.

I followed [these instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-redhat-centos-or-fedora-linux/) during installation

Running

```
service mongod start
```

results in

```
Starting mongod (via systemctl):  Job failed. See system journal and 'systemctl status' for details.  [FAILED]
```

So I ran

```
systemctl status mongod.service
```

which gives me

```
mongod.service - SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database.
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon, 18 Jun 2012 13:15:56 +0200; 58s ago
 Process: 13584 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  CGroup: name=systemd:/system/mongod.service
```

Mongo logs in `/var/log/mongo/mongod.log` is empty

Thanks

Comment: What are your access rights for `/var/log/mongo` and `/var/log/mongo/mongod.log`? Did you configure your data directory and how?

Comment: `/var/log/mongo` is `drwxr-xr-x` and `/var/log/mongo/mongod.log` is `-rw-r-----`. In mongo.conf I have `dbpath=/var/lib/mongo` Thnx

Comment: Have you tried what you get if you run `mongod` directly from shell?

Comment: I just tried that and told me `/data/db` didn't exist, so created it and ran it again and it works. But `sudo service mongod start` still fails

Comment: I'm suspecting that mongod as service is not running under correct user. Have you double-checked that?

Comment: mongodb is shipped directly within fedora. I suggest you to uninstall it (yum erase mongodb), remove the yum repository you added as per your linked instructions, and install again fedora own rpm (yum install mongodb again). It has probablt been fixed to work nicely with systemd and will have had some custom fedora configuration as well.

Comment: @jsalonen according to the script it uses mongod user. Important thing is that I can run it now. Not too bothered about the rest. If you want to post an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: @guido didnt quite work either

Comment: You should use the 10gen repository to keep up to date with MongoDB releases. Please see this link (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-redhat-centos-or-fedora-linux/) for full, detailed instructions on how to install, implement and run Mongo on CentOS. It references all the clean files. If "sudo service mongod start" isn't working, have you checked /var/log/mongo/mongod.log? Also, are you in the 'sudoers' list or are you logged in as root?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

How to install mongodb and mongodb-server on fedora linux (verified on f16 & f17). All commands are intended to be run in a su session.

1) make sure you have no mongodb installation lying around

```
# yum erase mongodb
# yum erase mongo-10gen  (if it is installed)
```

2) install from fedora yum repository

```
# yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=fedora,updates install mongodb mongodb-server
```

3) start mongod (mongodb daemon)

```
# systemctl start mongod.service
```

4) verify mongod is running

```
# systemctl status mongod.service
# tail /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
# nmap -p27017 localhost
```

or running client

```
# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.2
connecting to: test
> db.test.save( { a: 1 } )
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fdf28f09d16204d66082fa3"), "a" : 1 }
```

5) customize configuration

```
# vim /etc/mongodb.conf
# systemctl restart mongod.service
```

6) make mongodb service automatically start at boot

```
# systemctl enable mongod.service
```

**Update for Fedora 18**

When started for the first time by systemd on a slow or loaded machine, mongod service might timeout before finishing its initialization, with systemd flagging the service as failed.

Symptoms:

```
# journalctl -xn

-- Unit mongod.service has begun starting up.
10:38:43 local mongod[24558]: forked process: 24560
10:38:43 local mongod[24558]: all output going to: /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
10:40:13 local systemd[1]: mongod.service operation timed out. Terminating.
10:40:13 local systemd[1]: Failed to start High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed
```

Very easy cure, restart the service:

```
# systemctl restart mongod.service
```

this should finish the initialization successfully and leave the daemon in running state.

Comment: Do you really need `sudo` in root scripts?

Comment: Type [sudo su] on terminal and the root's password, before commands above.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and in my case it was caused by installing mongodb following instructions of some websites using non-official repo. If you have the same issue and the answer above are not solving your problem, try uninstalling "mongodb-org" package and reinstalling it following the instructions of the official documentation : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/

Remainder to uninstall package in fedora:

```
sudo dnf remove <package-name>
```