# Fedora MongoDB issue Installing

Tags: mongodb, service, fedora

I've installed mongoDB on fedora 17 and the server don't running.

I got the same error in this post [MongoDB service not running in Fedora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081822/mongodb-service-not-running-in-fedora)  and then and try to fallow this instruction and I got another error

Trying to do this

```
 yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=fedora,updates install mongodb mongodb-server 

I got this Error
    Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/bin/bsondump from install of mongodb-2.0.2-10.fc17.x86_64 conflicts with       file from package mongo-10gen-2.0.6-mongodb_1.x86_64

  file /usr/bin/mongo from install of mongodb-2.0.2-10.fc17.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongo-10gen-2.0.6-mongodb_1.x86_64

  file /usr/bin/mongodump from install of mongodb-2.0.2-10.fc17.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongo-10gen-2.0.6-mongodb_1.x86_64

  file /usr/bin/mongoexport from install of mongodb-2.0.2-10.fc17.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongo-10gen-2.0.6-mongodb_1.x86_64

  file /usr/bin/mongofiles from install of mongodb-2.0.2-10.fc17.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongo-10gen-2.0.6-mongodb_1.x86_64

  file /usr/bin/mongoimport from install of mongodb-2.0.2-10.fc17.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongo-10gen-2.0.6-mongodb_1.x86_64
```

file /usr/bin/mongorestore from install of mongodb-2.0.2-10.fc17.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongo-10gen-2.0.6-mongodb_1.x86_64

```
  file /usr/bin/mongostat from install of mongodb-2.0.2-10.fc17.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongo-10gen-2.0.6-mongodb_1.x86_64

  file /usr/bin/mongotop from install of mongodb-2.0.2-10.fc17.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongo-10gen-2.0.6-mongodb_1.x86_64
```

file /etc/sysconfig/mongod from install of mongodb-server-2.0.2-10.fc17.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongo-10gen-server-2.0.6-mongodb_1.x86_64

```
  file /usr/bin/mongod from install of mongodb-server-2.0.2-10.fc17.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongo-10gen-server-2.0.6-mongodb_1.x86_64

  file /usr/bin/mongos from install of mongodb-server-2.0.2-10.fc17.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mongo-10gen-server-2.0.6-mongodb_1.x86_64
```

### Error Summary

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you've already installed the [10gen packages](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-redhat-centos-or-fedora-linux/) for MongoDB 2.0.6.  The conflicts are caused by trying to also install the default Fedora packaged version of MongoDB (2.0.2 from your error messages) which includes binaries with the same name.

Instead of reinstalling, you should be able to [start the MongoDB service](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-redhat-centos-or-fedora-linux/#start-mongodb) as root or using sudo:

```
service mongod start
```

With the 10gen packaged install you should find:

- `/etc/mongod.conf` for changing configuration options
- default data directory: `/var/lib/mongo`
- default log file directory: `/var/log/mongo`
- the init script at: `/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod`