# MongoDB won't start on Fedora/Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, mongodb, fedora

Just finished installing mongodb using

```
sudo yum install mongodb
```

But when I try running 'mongo' for a rails app I get

```
[thiago@netbox mongoExample]$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.4
connecting to: test
Wed Aug 21 16:07:56 exec error: src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:91 couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017
db = new Mongo().getDB( url );
     ^

exception: connect failed
```

I have also tried:

```
[thiago@netbox mongoExample]$ service mongo start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mongo.service
Failed to issue method call: Access denied
[thiago@netbox mongoExample]$ sudo service mongo start
[sudo] password for thiago: 
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mongo.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit mongo.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status mongo.service' for details.

[thiago@netbox mongoExample]$ systemctl status mongo.service
mongo.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I tried following their documentation (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/) with no luck.

I appreciate any help.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question is a better fit on Serverfault.com or maybe superuser.com.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081822/mongodb-service-not-running-in-fedora/11083391#11083391